# Strange behavior when start task recursively

Tags: android, task, history, back

Maybe the title can cause some confusing, but I can't find a better way to name my issue.
I have 3 activities, defined with separate taskAffinity in manifest file (for example A, B, C). At first, I start activity A, which start task A. Then I press Home button and the home screen is shown. Next, I start activity B, which start task B. On the screen of activity B there is a button, when clicked will start activity C. At this moment the stack is as following (using dumpsys command). *my.package.Home* is my self-defined Home application.

> Recent tasks:
>    * Recent #0: TaskRecord{421c0998 #111 A=my.package.C U=0 sz=2}
>    * Recent #1: TaskRecord{42133508 #110 A=my.package.B U=0 sz=2}
>    * Recent #2: TaskRecord{41cf77c0 #1 A=my.package.Home U=0 sz=4}
>    * Recent #3: TaskRecord{428124d8 #103 A=my.package.A U=0 sz=2}

On activity C also there is a button to start activity B, and after the B is started from C, the task stack is reordered, telling from below dumpsys output.

> Recent tasks:
>    * Recent #0: TaskRecord{42133508 #110 A=my.package.B U=0 sz=2}
>    * Recent #1: TaskRecord{421c0998 #111 A=my.package.C U=0 sz=2}
>    * Recent #2: TaskRecord{41cf77c0 #1 A=my.package.Home U=0 sz=4}
>    * Recent #3: TaskRecord{428124d8 #103 A=my.package.A U=0 sz=2}

Then the problem is, from above status, if I press Back button twice, instead the Home screen is displayed as expected, activity A is shown.
I have a decent experience in Android, but have no clue what's the background of this strange behavior. Anyone can help me figure out whether this is a designed behavior or Android`s bug. And how to bypass it the acquire my expected behavior?

**Updated:** this seems to be an Android 4.x specific issue. On a 6.0 device, no strange behavior with the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set custom flags to activities on manifest file to avoid that problem

`android:launchMode=["standard" | "singleTop" | "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]`

You can check here what means each of them

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Actually I tried many solutions, including your suggestion, but no luck. It seems that is a bug of Android 4.x. I tried the same app on android 6.0 and no problem.